# Java. Eliminar un elemento de un ArrayList al que tengo que acceder a través de dos atributos

Tags: java, arraylist, iteradores, eliminar

Tengo que hacer un ArrayList Ticket de objetos de tipo Articulo, nos dicen que el atributo codigoArticulo puede estar repetido. Nos piden elaborar un metodo para eliminar elementos del ArrayList en el que tenemos que seleccionar el Articulo a eliminar a través de codigoArticulo, pero en el caso de que estuviera repetido debemos de emplear otro atributo que no esté repetido para eliminarlo, por ejemplo precioArticulo. A través de un bucle for:each no puedo realizar la operación y a traves de un iterador no se cómo hacerlo. Sabe alguien cómo hacerlo?
El código que adjunto no es valido porque al usar dos veces it.next() me salta dos articulos.

```
public class Ticket{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Articulos art1 = new Articulos(111, "lana", 29);//CodigoArticulo,composicion,precio
        Articulos art2 = new Articulos(111, "piel", 39);
        

        ArrayList<Cliente_1> ticket=new ArrayList<Articulos>(); 
        
        ticket.add(art1);
        ticket.add(art2);           
                                                                        
        Iterator<Articulos> it= ticket.iterator();          //02
        
         while (it.hasNext()) {

               int codigosArticulosColeccion = it.next().getCodigo();
               double preciosArticulosColeccion = it.next().getPrecio();
                        
               if (codigosArticulosColeccion == codigo && preciosArticulosColeccion== precio) {

                      it.remove();//elimina al objeto que cumple la condición del if

                      System.out.println("El articulo se ha eliminado correctamente");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Y por qué no lo guardas en una variable local?? `Articulos articulo = it.next();` y luego usas ese articulo para leer el precio y el código. Porque obviamente hacer dos `next()` te va a sacar dos elementos diferentes! Otra opción mucho más corta sería: `ticket.removeIf(art -> art.getCodigo() == codigo && art.getPrecio() == precio);`, que requiere java 8 al menos

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado la segunda opción que me has recomendado.